# android studio toString method is not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods, tostring

i'm working on a project in android studio but when i want to use toString() method it shows : cannot resolve method 'toString()'.please check the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKWt.jpg)

```
etLPassword = findViewById(R.id.etLPassword);
    String password = etLPassword.getText().toString();
```

tostring() appears with red color

Comment: Please show the full error message.  Also, please don't post your code on this site as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image.  For more on this, please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/522444). Also please check out the [ask] for more on-site best-practices.

Comment: thanks,i just modified the question

Comment: What type is etLPassword variable? What is the return type of getText() ?

Most likely getText either is returning a primitive, or it's void... Any object would have a toString() method implementation

Comment: Looks like an EditText. I dunno; it's like your IDE is messed up or something. Does it fail if you try to compile?

Comment: yes it shows like there is no method like that